# Sphinx Confluence Builder publishing to the Confluence V2 Editor

Tags: python-sphinx, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am using sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder to publish my Python documentation to Confluence cloud.

It creates labeled pages with the header/footer macros I need but it does so in the old Editor V1 format.

I haven't been able to find a config setting to tell it to use the Confluence V2 editor format.  Is there a way to do so?

Also, the various extensions (myst-parser, m2r2 etc) for processing MD files work fine when outputting HTML but don't seem to take effect when publishing to Confluence.  I'm using shell scripting and awk to convert MD to RST files but is there a better way?

Eventually this is going to run within a GitHub workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension as of v2.x now supports the "v2" (Fabric) editor format. This can be configured using the [`confluence_editor`](https://sphinxcontrib-confluencebuilder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration/#confval-confluence_editor) option:

```
confluence_editor = 'v2'
```

There are limitations when using the editor, which are outlined in the extension's documentation and demonstration pages.

*Disclosure: I am a maintainer for the Atlassian Confluence Builder for Sphinx extension.*